# Apache redirect changing all occurrences of url inside url

Tags: string, .htaccess, redirect, replace

I have to redirect a url which is having the url also several times inside the url and all occurrences must be replaced. aslo there is a port number used in the url.

E.G.
https://old.url.com:9443/foo/web#URI=https%3A%2F%2Fold.url.com%3A9443%2Ffoo%2Fweb2%2conf=https%3A%2F%2Fold.url.com%3A9443%2Fxxx

should be replaced with

https://new.url.com:9443/foo/web#URI=https%3A%2F%2Fnew.url.com%3A9443%2Ffoo%2Fweb2%2conf=https%3A%2F%2Fnew.url.com%3A9443%2Fxxx

Regards
Helmut

I tried my luck with https://htaccess.madewithlove.com but yet I didnt succeed, any help is really welcome.

Comment: There seems to be a miss understanding here: the part following the hash character (#) will _never_ get sent to an http server by a client (a browser). It is exclusively interpreted on the client side. Which means that rewriting won't even see that part of a URL in a request, which is why it cannot rewrite it. The sole exception is clients other than browsers that follow a different logic, which is questionable but possible. For example an fat client application that actively sends such requests to an API.

Comment: Ok then whats to do to get this changed ? I need a kind of a proxy server (not a browser) which gets this complete url , exchanges the string  old.url to new.url and sends it to new.url

Comment: Once more: no browser will send that anchor part of the URL. So neither a http server nor any proxy in between will ever see a request to that. That simply is how browsers act. Question is why you need to rewrite that at all. What kind of client is that and were does that link come from?

Comment: We have lots of links with that old urls in our documentations and those all don't work anymore. So would it be possible to use a javascript which gets all those parameters, or is it only the browser getting those ?

Comment: You can handle such things on the client side, sure, javascript is the typical tool there. I'd say it makes more sense to replace the links in the documentation (global search and replace instead of having to implement a coding solution. But I don't know your exact setup, you know better. In Javascript you have access to the browser's location object where you can indeed simply change the URL if I recall correctly (not my field of work at all for the last decade ...). If you want to give that approach a shot I recommend to open a separate question using matching tags.